# Python code to merge multiple .wav files from multiple folders gets hung up

Tags: python, operating-system, iteration, wave

I have a bunch of wave files from an outdoor bird recorder that are broken up into 1 hour segments. Each days worth of audio is in a single folder and I have 30 days worth of folders. I am trying to iterate through the folders an merge each days audio into one file and export it with the folder name but each time i try to run it the print statements indicate that each for loop runs to completion before the merge function can be called, or it runs properly and the merge funtion throws a write error.

```
import wave
import os

#creates an empty object for the first folder name
rootfiles= ""

#sets the path for the starting location    
path = "I:\SwiftOne_000"

#lists all folders in the directory "path"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)

print("Files and directories in '", path, "' :")

#iterates through folders in path
for i in dir_list:
    #adds file name to original path
    rootfiles = ( path + "\\" + i)

   
    prefix = i
    
    # define outfiles for waves
    out_name = prefix
   
    
    print("first loop completed")
for x in rootfiles:

        myfiles= []
        paths = rootfiles
        ext = (".wav")
        #print(paths)
        dir_lists = os.listdir(paths)
        #print(dir_lists)
        #print("Files and directories in '", paths, "' :")
        print("second loop completed")
for x in dir_lists:
    
    myfiles.append( paths + "\\" + x)
        
    #print (myfiles)
    
   
    outfile= "D:\SwiftD\prefix" + prefix + ".wav"
    wav_files = myfiles
   
    print("third loop completed")
 

from contextlib import closing

with closing(wave.open(outfile, 'wb')) as output:

    # find sample rate from first file
    with closing(wave.open(wav_files[0])) as w:
        output.setparams(w.getparams())

    # write each file to output
    for infile in wav_files:
        with closing(wave.open(infile)) as w:
            output.writeframes(w.readframes(w.getnframes()))
```

Comment: select code and use `Ctrl+K` to format it.

Comment: `wont run` is totally useless information. We can't run it to see what is the problem. You have to describe it in question. And if you get error message when you run it in console/terminal then show it error (as text) in question (not in comments)

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: `rootfiles = os.path.join(path, i)`

Comment: \ has special meaning in string - even in path - so better use always \\ in path - ie. `"D:\\SwiftD\\prefix"`, or use prefix `r` for `raw string` - ie. `r"D:\SwiftD\prefix"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, assuming your folder structure is:

```
- Swift (directory)
  - Day1 (directory)
    - File1
    - File2
    - File3
```

```
import os, wave

src = r'I:\SwiftOne_000'
output_folder = r'I:\OutputFolder'

input_data = {}
for d_name, d_path in [(d, path) for d in os.listdir(src) if os.path.isdir(path := os.path.join(src, d))]:
    input_data[d_name] = [path for f in os.listdir(d_path) if f.lower().endswith('.wav') and os.path.isfile(path := os.path.join(d_path, f))]

print(input_data)

for d_name, paths in input_data.items():
    with wave.open(os.path.join(output_folder, f'{d_name}.wav'), 'wb') as output:
        params_written = False
        for path in paths:
            with wave.open(path, 'rb') as data:
                if not params_written:
                    output.setparams(data.getparams())
                    params_written = True
                output.writeframes(data.readframes(data.getnframes()))
```

There are a few issues with your code. It better to use `os.path.join` to concatentate paths rather than constructing the string yourself as it makes it platform independent (although you probably don't care). `os.listdir` will return files and folders so you should check the type with `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.isdir` to be sure. The case for the file extension isn't always in lower case so your extension check might not work; using `.lower()` means you can always check for `.wav`.

I'm pretty sure you don't need `contentlib closing` as the `with` block will already take care of this for you.

You are using the `outfile` variable to write to the file, however, you overwrite this each time you loop around the third loop, so you will only ever get one file corresponding to the last directory.

Without seeing the stack trace, I'm not sure what the write error is likely to be.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you are a lifesaver! I ran your code and it started to work on the first try, the only issue is it merged the files in the first and last day folders and then threw an "argument out of range" error for line 13. Id been having this same issue with the write command in the wave.open line.

Comment: If add you add a stack trace it would be useful to see where it is failing. Could you be trying to read the same directory you're writing to?